# Suspicious Questions

Tags: discussion

Just wondering some questions I see on security.stackexchange.com seem very destructive. Some questions it's quite obvious what they are trying to do is illegal like "How do I hack my neighbors wifi" Should I answer these questions? or should I flag the question? I am unsure I don't feel it is right help people in illegal/destructive activities. I am unsure if my question is in the right place if it's not could you kindly please let me know where I should be posting the question.

Comment: Have you read http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/q/897/971?

Comment: No but thank you your comment answered my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are most definitely not here to help anyone do anything illegal. Feel free to flag "how do I hack a network"-type posts without hesitation wherever and whenever you see them. I certainly wouldn't help anyone do anything blatantly illegal, but more generally, you shouldn't really ever feel *obligated* to answer any particular question. Your time is valuable; when you spend it helping out on Stack Exchange, you should at least be enjoying yourself.

Please note that the exact outcome of flags on suspicious questions may not always be the same. If we look into one and find someone maliciously spamming multiple sites, we'll have a different reaction than we would for a user who's just frustrated over forgetting the password to a home router.